# While using .loc with '&' ,why is output showing 'Empty DataFrame'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code and output shows "Empty DataFrame"

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

df_excel = pd.read_excel("test Data.xlsx")

print (df_excel.loc[(df_excel['Dist'] == "Sagar") & (df_excel['Site Potential'] == 200)])
```

Is there any error in the last line of the code?

The expected output should show all the entries with Dist "Sagar" and "Site Potential" =200. Manually,I can check that there are 2 such entries in the test file.

Comment: How do you expect someone to be able to help you if you don't share the data that allows us to reproduce the same result?  Please read  [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Why are using `loc` at all here?  You should be able to delete `.loc`, and the "magic indexing" will do its thing.

Comment: maybe first check what you get with `print( df_excel.loc[df_excel['Site Potential'] == 200] )` and `print( df_excel.loc[df_excel['Dist'] == "Sagar"] )` . And check if there are rows with both values at the same time. OR maybe it needs string `"200"` ?